# Bootstrap Lightbox. How to use simple example in own site?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter, lightbox

I'm trying to integrate Bootstrap Lightbox with my own twitter bootstrap site. How to use example from http://jbutz.github.com/bootstrap-lightbox/#demo

in my code? What do I need to import?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Template &middot; Bootstrap</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <!-- Le styles -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <style type="text/css">
      body {
        padding-top: 20px;
        padding-bottom: 40px;
      }

      /* Custom container */
      .container-narrow {
        margin: 0 auto;
        max-width: 700px;
      }
      .container-narrow > hr {
        margin: 30px 0;
      }

    </style>
    <link href="css/bootstrap-responsive.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- HTML5 shim, for IE6-8 support of HTML5 elements -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="http://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->


  </head>

  <body>

    <div class="container-narrow">

      <div class="masthead">
        <ul class="nav nav-pills pull-right">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Nothing</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        </ul>
        <h3 class="muted">My site</h3>
      </div>

      <hr>



      <div class="footer">
        <p>&copy; Company 2012</p>
      </div>

    </div> <!-- /container -->

    <!-- Le javascript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-transition.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-alert.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-modal.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-dropdown.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-scrollspy.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-tab.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-tooltip.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-popover.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-button.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-collapse.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-carousel.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap-typeahead.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

What files are required? Thanks

Answer (score 13):

I tend to use the built in twitter bootstrap modal dialog for this:

The full information is available on the official bootstrap site:

http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

If you scroll down you will see a 'Launch demo modal' button like below:

[image: launch demo button]

Selecting this displays the model like this:

[image: launched modal]

The full details on how to implement this are detailed in the site.